# Javascript RAW drag&drop implementation for mobile (touch) devices

Tags: javascript, mobile, drag-and-drop

I've been searching for this kind of sollution but with no results.

Comment: For **any** touch device ?

Comment: Actually for tablests using Android and IOS! Sorry for not giving that info